# Why am I getting a HTTP 400 bad request error?

Tags: php, http, curl, http-status-code-400

```
<?php
$url ="http://absolutesms.com/Sendsms.aspx?userid=userid&password=password&clientid=clientid&senderid=absolute&mobilenumber=919000024365&smsmessage=SingleMessage".$request;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

After running this code I am getting `HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed`. What should I do? I tried other url they are working fine the only problem is with this.
If I copy this url in browser it's working but it's giving error 400 when I put it and run it in curl.

Answer (score 3):

I see this a lot. Usually fixed by running the request through urlencode().

Answer (score 2):

Try building URL with http_build_query as below

```
$url = 'http://absolutesms.com/Sendsms.aspx?' . http_build_query(array(
    'userid' => $userid,
    'clientid' => $clientid,
///... continue
));
```

The problem is probably due to `unescaped characters that have special meanings in URLs`.

`http_build_query` escapes them for you safely.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `$request` at the end of the assignment to `$url` but you don't show us what `$request` contains.

Chances are that the value of `$request` tacked on the end that way is making the URL invalid.

I would expect to at least see a `&` at the end of the hardcoded URL string if you are going to append `$request` like that (although as @MichaelKrelin-hacker points out, this is unlikely to be the source of this specific error).

Comment: The lack of `&` doesn't make URL invalid, even if it glues the next parameter to the last one. What is most likely to make url invalid is either its size or perhaps some awfully invalid characters.